# Usage of "Click" with "Menu"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I wrote:

> Hover the mouse over the item you want to add to the video, then right click and **select** 'Add to Content' **from** the menu (pop-up menu).

First, did I use "select" and "from" correctly? Can I use "click on" instead of "select", while keeping the "from the menu"?
How can I use "click" with "menu" in this sentence?

Comment: Is the 'Ad to content ' a checkbox or what ? is the Menu in form of list ?

Comment: @Cardinal It is an item in a pop-up menu.

Comment: Oh I see, I feel stupid !! :D

Comment: That's the standard way to phrase it. Your substitutions work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your description is grammatically correct, but it is somewhat longer than necessary. "Hover" is typically used when something is expected to happen without any clicking, but that's not the case here. You could use a shorter instruction:

> Right-click the item you want to add to the video, and select 'Add to Content' from the pop-up menu.

Note that "right-click" is a compound verb and should include a hyphen.

As for the second part of your question: in most user interfaces, the action you do with a menu is selecting, not just clicking, because it has a side effect of closing the menu.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, however the user should hover the mouse over an element (HTML element on the page) so that the item under it gets highlighted and then right-click....